# IMAP qprint is not decoding danish charecter?

Tags: php, email, utf-8, imap

I have completed PHP IMAP code. All the mail result is coming fine. But in the mail if contain any danish character then it show wrong. The code I have done for finding message body is below,

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
if($emails) {
    rsort($emails);
    $total_mail=imap_num_msg($inbox);
    echo 'Number of email:'.$total_mail;
    /* for every email… */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

            if(isset($structure->parts) && is_array($structure->parts) && isset($structure->parts[1])) {
                $part = $structure->parts[1];
                $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

                if($part->encoding == 3) {
                    $message = imap_base64($message);
                } else if($part->encoding == 1) {
                    $message = imap_8bit($message);
                } else {
                    $message = imap_qprint($message);
                }

            }
```

As a example the message in the mail is, `Låt deras önskningar gå i uppfyllelse i år med perfekta klappar från Apple.`, and it is showing in he above code output as `L�t deras �nskningar g� i uppfyllelse i �r med perfekta klappar fr�n Apple.`.

I don't know the problem. I have follow all the rules. The charset is also UTF-8 like, `charset="UTF-8"`. But sill have the same problem.

Please help me to solve this. Advance thanks for help.

Comment: It's Swedish, not Danish.